# Wordpress AJAX 400 when registered in Shortcode Plugin

Tags: wordpress

I'm writing a custom shortcode that will need to call some PHP file via AJAX, after some user event. But I am getting Bad Request 400 as if my wp_ajax_* actions aren't being registered.

I have tried rearranging the order in which I add actions and enqueue my scripts but nothing seems to work.

Here is my simple plugin code

```php
function aj_ajax_demo_shortcode() {
    return '<h4>Shortcode</h4>';
}
add_shortcode( 'ajax_demo', 'aj_ajax_demo_shortcode' );

add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_aj_ajax_demo', 'aj_ajax_demo_process' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_aj_ajax_demo', 'aj_ajax_demo_process' );
function aj_ajax_demo_process() {
    wp_send_json((object) array('msg' => 'hello world'));
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'aj_enqueue_scripts' );
function aj_enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'aj-demo', 
        plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'aj-demo-ajax-code.js'
    );

    wp_localize_script(
        'aj-demo',
        'aj_ajax_demo',
        array(
            'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
            'aj_demo_nonce' => wp_create_nonce('aj-demo-nonce') 
        )
    );
}
```

And the JS:

```
fetch(aj_ajax_demo.ajax_url, {
    method: 'POST',
    data: {
        action : 'aj_ajax_demo',
        nonce : aj_ajax_demo.aj_demo_nonce,
    }
}).then(response => {
    if (response.ok) {
        response.json().then(response => {
            console.log(response);
        });
    }
});
```

I'm struggling to get my AJAX function to even be called, and I can't see where I have done something wrong, especially given the small amount of code I have.

Answer (score 0):

You don't send any post variable to server. Use `FormData()`

```
  var formData  = new FormData();
  formData.append('action','aj_ajax_demo');
  formData.append('nonce',aj_ajax_demo.aj_demo_nonce);
```

and then:

```
fetch(aj_ajax_demo.ajax_url, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: formData
}).then(response => {
    if (response.ok) {
        response.json().then(response => {
            console.log(response);
        });
    }
});
```